# can TTURLMap from three20 map to a xib-file?

Tags: iphone, ipad, three20

ive made an app for the iphone and wanted to make it work on an ipad too.
for the navigation i used three20. all the views are viewcontrollers with xib´s.

for later developement, i just wanted to make the xibs in the bigger format as new skin and let the background-programm the same, so that in the end each viewcontroller would have 2 xib´s as skins.

so, three20´s URLMap can link to class-files. but how can i link to a xib ?

i wanted in the appdelegate to make the URLMap depending on the device, so that the programm it self can stay as is with its URL-Calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, now i used to overwrite the initWithNibName in combination with [UIDevice currentDevice].model to let the viewcontroller check, on which device he loads